# What are the measures to take when a linux box is being probed?

Tags: linux

I have installed logwatch on one of the VPS I have online running ubuntu 10.04. Kindly find the content of the logwatch email on [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/9249211) .

Comment: People here are really quick to downvote. I guess everyone is an expert so no need to post here.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore it.

What you see there is the sort of routine, automated scan that constitutes the "background noise" of the Internet.  Make sure your software is up to date, and don't worry too much.

Comment: When running 10.04 it's not an option anymore to keep software up to date.

Comment: @SPRBRN - 10.04 is a LTS release that's good for 3 years on the Desktop and 5 years as a server -- black sensei still has 11 months to upgrade.  Important security patches are backported, granted you won't have new versions available.  This is often a good thing; e.g., 10.04 still uses the 0.9.8 line of OpenSSL so was never vulnerable to Heartbleed (on the other hand never supported TLS 1.1/1.2).

Comment: You're correct, I thought it was only for 3 years supported.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @mark's answer, any machine that you put straight on the Internet, make sure it's hardened:

1.) **Install up to date software (if possible)**.  In fact, make sure your OS is also up to date.  Software manufacturers bring out new versions with security fixes all the time, make sure you have them; else your machine would be compromised quickly.

2.) **Enable only the services you need.**  If you only want to server webpages and nothing else, make sure you're not running an FTP server, a mail gateway, etc...  Do minimal installations and cut out the fat.

3.) **Block access to ports** . Your OS comes with a built in firewall; iptables.  Configure it correctly and only expose the (up to date) services to the Internet.  There are 3rd party programs that will allow you to temporarily ban connections from brute forcing IP addresses.

Another, albeit security-through-obscurity approach, is that you can run some services on non-standard ports.  But that won't scare too many away.

You'll always get password tries and scans of services on your machine, as Mark said, it's the background noise of the Internet.

Comment: Running 10.04 is just asking to be compromised...

Comment: 10.04 is LTS and support is good till 2015 ?